# CCXT okex5 swap contracts - Parameter posSide error

Tags: python, rest, trading, cryptoapi, ccxt

I am trying to create a perpetual limit order using ccxt on okex exchange version 5.
The API is successfully placing orders(both limit and market) on spot exchange but not on perpetual exchange.
Here is what I am trying -

```
exchange_swap = ccxt.okex5({
'apiKey': credentials['okex']['apikey'],
'secret': credentials['okex']['secretkey'],
'password': credentials['okex']['password'],
'options': {
    'defaultType': 'swap', 
      }
})
params =  {
   "test":True
}
order = exchange_swap.createLimitBuyOrder('XRP-USDT-SWAP',100,0.7)
```

Error message-

```
ccxt.base.errors.BadRequest: okex5 {"code":"1","data":[{"clOrdId":"","ordId":"","sCode":"51000","sMsg":"Parameter posSide  error ","tag":""}],"msg":""}
```

After searching about this error I found this in their documentation-

```
Error message           Http status code     Error code
Parameter {0} error.    400                  51000
```

Documentation link - [Okex v5](https://www.okex.com/docs-v5/en/#error-code-rest-public)

P.S - I am able to place this via trading dashboard on okex but not through the API. I have enough balance to create this order.

Entire error message is this-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\Crypto Vibhor\Testing Files\ccxt_test.py", line 70, in 
 <module>
  order = exchange_swap.createLimitBuyOrder('XRP-USDT-SWAP',100,0.7)
  File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 1983, in create_limit_buy_order
return self.create_order(symbol, 'limit', 'buy', amount, price, params)
 File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\okex5.py", line 1287, in create_order
response = self.privatePostTradeOrder(self.extend(request, params))
File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 461, in inner
return entry(_self, **inner_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 
 486, in request
  return self.fetch2(path, api, method, params, headers, body)
  File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 482, in fetch2
  return self.fetch(request['url'], request['method'], request['headers'], request['body'])
  File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 634, in fetch
  self.handle_errors(http_status_code, http_status_text, url, method, headers, http_response, json_response, request_headers, request_body)
  File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\okex5.py", line 2230, in handle_errors
  self.throw_exactly_matched_exception(self.exceptions['exact'], errorCode, feedback)
  File "C:\Users\ishaa\Desktop\trading\tradingenv\lib\site-packages\ccxt\base\exchange.py", line 500, in throw_exactly_matched_exception
   raise exact[string](message)
   ccxt.base.errors.BadRequest: okex5 {"code":"1","data": 
   [{"clOrdId":"","ordId":"","sCode":"51000","sMsg":"Parameter posSide  error 
    ","tag":""}],"msg":""}
```

Answer (score 4):

This could happen if you have the wrong `Order Placement Mode` in your OKX account settings.
Go to your OKX account > trade > perpetual swap > setting > order placement mode and set it to `Long/Short mode`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says `Parameter posSide error` which means you have an error in the `posSide` paramater you are sending in your request.

As far as I can see from your code you have only provided the ticker, size and price but are missing the `posSide` parameter.

Contrary to other exchanges, on Okex you can `buy` or `sell` a `long` or `short` for `FUTURES` and `SWAP` products so you need to add the `posSide` parameter.

It's counter intuitive and took me some time to figure out as well. Effectively you can both `buy` a `long` and `buy` a `short` at the same time. You can try it out in the Okex gui to see exactly how it works.

The docs tell us that `posSide` parameter is:

[image]

Another option is to disable the `long/short` mode (which is set by default) and use `net` mode instead. Using `net` mode means you won't need to add the `posSide` parameter to your request string.

Here is the link to the docs which explain how to [set the position mode](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#rest-api-account-set-position-mode).

And here is a working example which includes two requeired parameters for a limit order, namely setting `tdMode` and `posSide`:

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.okex5({
    'apiKey': '...',
    'secret': '...',
    'password': '...',
})

exchange.createLimitBuyOrder('XRP-USDT-SWAP', 100, 0.4,
                             {"tdMode": "cross", "posSide": "long"})
```

You can read more about setting Custom Order Params in the ccxt doc [here](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html?#custom-order-params).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue in 2024, it's called `Position Mode` and it's value should be `One-way mode` in Perp Settings as pointed out in [@x-6-2-5's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761510/2041598) answer.

The same error can be seen when using the ATAS Platform for OKX Crypto.